# Django downgrade from 1.9 to 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to use a Django package that is only compatible with Django 1.8, so I think I should downgrade my current project from 1.9 to 1.8. What would be the best course of action for achieving that?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear. I was asking about how to do that and not have any errors. Like what has been deprecated in 1.9

Comment: @wim you should post it as answer so it can be upvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To downgrade Django to the most recent release in the version 1.8 series:

```
pip install "Django~=1.8.0"
```

[This ~= syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release) means to install the latest point release that is backwards-compatible with 1.8.  At the time of writing, that's `v1.8.18`, however should a `v1.8.19` be released at a later date the command shown above would select it instead.

For a list of what has been deprecated in 1.9, you should review the release notes here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/